# In MVC, should pure View events be handled in the Controller?

Tags: c#, mvc

Let's say I have a form with a black label. I have a button that is supposed to change the label color to red.

This functionality has nothing to do with the data layer (the Model), but only with the `View`. So should the button click event be handled in the `Controller` or in the `View` itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking - the controller.

I get the feeling you're omitting the technologies you're working with here. For example, if you were to say this was a HTML5 SPA app and controllers are all server side, then I would just handle this in JS, in the client, which is technically, the view. But MVC can be realised again in the "view" (model binding and events on view state for example), as well as between the client and server. So it really depends on the details of what you're dealing with.

Comment: I am using C# WinForms. So the View is a `Form`, and the Model and Controller are classes I created.

Comment: Why are you using the MVC pattern in a C# WinForm application?

Comment: Why not? I am pretty new to design patterns so I am just learning. :)

Comment: Because technically you're already in a "controller", when you're placing code inside an event handler :).

Comment: I actually subscribe to the `Click` event in a View method called "SetEvents", and not using the designer for it. So for example, I do this: `button.Click += controller.button_Click;`. So the event handler is actually in the Controller.

Comment: Actually, after reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference, my code seems to be more of `MVP` then `MVC`.

Comment: It can be a good exercise to try and recreate MVP/MVC in WinForms, certainly not easier than doing it in a web environment, but sure you can do it. As you pointed out above in that link, it already is doing MVP for you without the need of seperate 'controller' classes, as also would a web SPA application based in HTML/JS would. It's good that you're exploring the patterns. Good luck.

Comment: @MartinBlore I have to disagree on your statement regarding a `Form` being a "controller".   A `Form` contains the widgets, fonts, colours, layout, etc; so it's very much a *View* (even if you split it across multiple files with `partial` it's still all the same class).        The goal of the MVC pattern is clean separation of behaviour away from layout/presentation, which means putting behaviour in a separate class independent of the View.     By putting behaviour inside the View/Form you effectively have no controller at all.

Comment: @BenCottrell You're right, the logic in response to the events is still inside the 'Form' class, which as you stated, is the container for all the view elements, a bunch of 'Control' objects in this case. I think it was the fact that the designer code is hidden away in the partial class that confused me. If it wasn't partial, then the event handling code would be the controller.